# Error transferring https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize?key=,myKey> - server replied: Bad Request [Problem on Windows OS]

Tags: qt, speech-to-text, google-cloud-speech, google-speech-to-text-api

I am using google speech-to-text api to convert my audio file to text. Following is my code(in Qt):

```
   `QString fileName = QDir::currentPath() + "/audio.wav"; //this is my audio file
    QFile audioFile(fileName);
    if(!audioFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)){
        QMessageBox::critical(0,"Error",fileName+" Not found!");
        ui->pushButton_4->setText("Speech to text");
        return;
    }
    int idx = ui->comboBox->currentIndex();
    QString enc;
    if (idx == -1)
        enc = "en-US";
    else
        enc = ui->comboBox->itemData(idx).toString(); //Language selected by user
    QByteArray audioData=audioFile.readAll();
    QUrl url("https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize");
    QUrlQuery query;
    query.addQueryItem("key","myKeyHere...");
    url.setQuery(query);
    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,"audio/x-flac");
    QJsonObject json;
    QJsonObject config;
    config["encoding"]="FLAC";
    config["sampleRateHertz"]=44100;
    config["languageCode"]=enc;
    json["config"]=config;
    QJsonObject audio;
    audio["content"]=QString::fromLatin1(audioData.toBase64());
    json["audio"]=audio;
    QByteArray jsonData=QJsonDocument(json).toJson();
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager=new QNetworkAccessManager();
    QNetworkReply *reply=manager->post(request,jsonData);
    QObject::connect(reply,&QNetworkReply::finished,[this,reply](){
        if(reply->error()!=QNetworkReply::NoError){
            QMessageBox::critical(0,"Error Occured",reply->errorString());
            qDebug() << reply->readAll();
            ui->pushButton_4->setText("Speech to text");
            return;
        }
        else if(reply->error()==QNetworkReply::UnknownNetworkError){
            QMessageBox::warning(0,"Network Error","Please check your internet connection and try again!");
            ui->pushButton_4->setText("Speech to text");
        }
        else if(reply->isFinished() && reply->error()==QNetworkReply::NoError){
            QJsonDocument responseJson=QJsonDocument::fromJson(reply->readAll());
            QJsonObject object=responseJson.object();
            QString ResponseText=object["results"].toArray()[0].toObject()
                    ["alternatives"].toArray()[0].toObject()["transcript"].toString();
            QTextCursor cur = curr_browser->textCursor();
            qDebug() << "Response Data :" << ResponseText;
            cur.insertText(ResponseText);
            ui->pushButton_4->setText("Speech to text");
        }
        reply->deleteLater();
    });`
```

This code is working perfectly on Ubuntu but not on windows. When i run this on Ubunutu, i am receiving the response, but on windows i receive the following error:
*Error transferring [https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize?key=,myKey>](https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize?key=,myKey%3E) - server replied: Bad Request*

Following is the code to record an audio file:

```
`if (m_audioRecorder->state() == QMediaRecorder::StoppedState) {
      QString fileName = QDir::currentPath() + "/audio.wav";
      m_audioRecorder->setOutputLocation(QUrl::fromLocalFile(fileName));
      qDebug()<<"Recording your audio!!";
      ui->pushButton_4->setText("Stop ?");
      QAudioEncoderSettings settings;
      settings.setCodec("audio/x-flac");
      settings.setSampleRate(0);
      settings.setBitRate(0);
      settings.setChannelCount(1);
      settings.setQuality(QMultimedia::EncodingQuality(2));
      settings.setEncodingMode(QMultimedia::ConstantQualityEncoding);

      m_audioRecorder->setEncodingSettings(settings, QVideoEncoderSettings(), "");
      m_audioRecorder->record();
  }
  else {
      qDebug()<<"stopped your recording!";
      ui->pushButton_4->setText("Processing ...");
      m_audioRecorder->stop();
      speechToTextCall(); //calling the code to send request to google api
  }`
```

Can anyone help please?

I tried changing the encodig and container type, but nothing worked on Windows.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution of above problem. Windows does not recognize the auido/x-flac encoding so i modified my encoding code as follows:
'

```
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
 settings.setCodec("audio/pcm");
 #else
 settings.setCodec("audio/x-flac");
 #endif
```

'
I made the same changes at other two places where encoding was set and it worked on windows as well.